# Show Content of Selected Options

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to show the content of the selected options in the span tags with corresponding id's.

So when you choose **Chocolate** as your ice cream flavor and **Caramel** as your topping, the text at the bottom will change to:

*"I love **Chocolate** ice cream with **Caramel**".*

```
<ul id="icecream" style="list-style:none;line-height:30px;">
  <li>
    <select id="icecream">
      <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
      <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
      <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select id="topping">
      <option value="sprinkles">Sprinkles</option>
      <option value="chocolatedip">Chocolate Dip</option>
      <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>I love <span id="icecreamFlavor"></span> ice cream with <span id="toppingFlavor"></span>.</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know of a javascript that can do this?

**Update:**
- Without using jQuery.
- Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry, Sprinkles, Chocolate Dip, and Caramel don't have to be displayed in **bold**.
- The first option in the select list is shown as default. I.e.:
*"I love **Vanilla** ice cream with **Sprinkles**".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    // wait for DOM content to finish loading
    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function DOMContentLoaded() {
      // no need to listen anymore
      this.removeEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', DOMContentLoaded );

      // get the DOM elements
      var icecream       = document.getElementById( 'icecream' );
      var topping        = document.getElementById( 'topping' );
      var icecreamFlavor = document.getElementById( 'icecreamFlavor' );
      var toppingFlavor  = document.getElementById( 'toppingFlavor' );

      // define an event listener that changes our output based on the selected options
      var onSelectChange = function( event ) {
        icecreamFlavor.textContent = icecream.options[ icecream.selectedIndex ].textContent;
        toppingFlavor.textContent  = topping.options[ topping.selectedIndex ].textContent;
      }

      // listen for the change events with the event listener
      icecream.addEventListener( 'change', onSelectChange );
      topping.addEventListener( 'change', onSelectChange );

      // initialize our output
      onSelectChange();
    } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul style="list-style:none;line-height:30px;">
  <li>
  <select id="icecream">
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
  </select>
  </li>
  <li>
  <select id="topping">
    <option value="sprinkles">Sprinkles</option>
    <option value="chocolatedip">Chocolate Dip</option>
    <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
  </select>
  </li>
  <li>I love <span id="icecreamFlavor"></span> ice cream with <span id="toppingFlavor"></span>.</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

*[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k3ayk0v2/)*

P.S.: Your `<ul>` had a conflicting `id` (`icecream`), so I had to remove it.

Comment: Thanks @DecentDabbler, your answer is very elaborate :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in javascript

```
$('#icecream').change(function(){    
    $('#icecreamFlavor').text($(this).val());
});

$('#topping').change(function(){   
    $('#toppingFlavor').text($(this).val());
});
```

Add the following code in css

```
#icecreamFlavor, #toppingFlavor{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this without jQuery? By using only javascript.

Comment: Check with this-                                                                     document.querySelector("#icecream").addEventListener('change', function(event){
 document.querySelector("#icecreamFlavor").innerHTML = event.value;
});
document.querySelector("#topping").addEventListener('change', function(event){
 document.querySelector("#toppingFlavor").innerHTML = event.value;
});

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

[Updated Javascript Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/msuL0yta/68/)

Change your 'ul' element id as 'iceCreamList' as there should be unique ids for html elements to identify them. Try this,

```
function selectIceCream(that){
    var iceCreamType  = that.options[that.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('icecreamFlavor').innerHTML = iceCreamType;
};

function selectToppings(that){
    var toppingType  = that.options[that.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('toppingFlavor').innerHTML = toppingType;
};
```

Also, you should consider placing the default options in your select list.

Comment: Thanks @VaibhavKatole, but your example shows the _value_ of an option, I would like it to show the _content_ of an option. I.e. _Chocolate Dip_ instead of _chocolatedip_. Could you change your code?

Comment: Glad to help @Macchiato, please see the updated answer and fiddle. It will solve your problem. :)